# Flutter change OnDoubleTap

Tags: firebase, flutter, button, toggle

in my App i want to do a like system. You can like the post by double tap the post. This works when you double tap for the first time, then its true. But when I want to unlike the post you have to double tap the post again and thats my problem. I want that if someone doubletap the second time its turn to false and the third time to true again bla bla... if someone know how please comment :)

```
bool isLiked = false;

Inkwell(
onDoubleTap(){


setState((){
      isLiked = true;
    });

print("You like the post");

if(isLiked)

 FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("LikeRoom").doc(firebaseUser.uid).set({uid : true} ,SetOptions(merge: true)).then((value){});

}else{

 FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("LikeRoom").doc(firebaseUser.uid).set({uid : false});

}

)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your `onDoubleTap` to negate the boolean. So it will always get from Like to Dislike and vice versa

```
setState((){
      isLiked = !isLiked;
    });
```